# MySQL Workbench auto complete box size too small on MacOS

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image: I have tried to find solutions on internet but couldn't find one. Is there any way to change the width of the auto completion box?]

[image]
Thanks
I have tried to find solutions on internet but couldn't find one. Is there any way to change the width of the auto completion box?

Comment: ok and why didn't you make a request at oracles tracker, there are not many settings for that if any

Comment: I believe this is just a setting thing but I couldn't find where I can fix. No way all MacOS users used it and didn't report it. I think it was just a setting problem of my computer. So I am expecting and finding a quick fix.

Comment: I have the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

'https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=108350'

Bug raised with developers.